# JQuery dialog does not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm working on a project in `Django`. I would like to add this dialog to my page [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/6fgqn/). It's simple dialog after click.

The problem is that it does not work but no errors visible in Chrome Inspect Console.

Do you know where is the problem?

I can see alert of `document ready` function, but I can't see the alert which should be visible after clicking on text.

This is in a head of `base.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="{% static "css/jumbotron.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "css/dropdown.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is the `.js` file:

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    alert('alert');
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('onready');
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function(){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });
});
```

This is a snippet I have in the `html`:

```
<div id="dialog">Your non-modal dialog</div>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
```

In case it helps, I'm attaching `html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block head %}

    {% load static %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
{#    <script src="{% static "js/setMyOrdersTableRowColors.js"%}"></script>#}
    <script src="{% static "js/myOrdersCommunication.js"%}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="dialog">Your non-modal dialog</div>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p class="btn">My Orders</p>
        {% render_table table %}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should move your click event into document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#open').click(function() {
        alert('alert');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');

    });

    alert('onready');
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function(){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Your problem is that you register click event on #id before that div exist.